# Google Chrome does not list specific FTP site content

Tags: google-chrome, ftp

When trying to access to a ftp site, i.e: ftp://ftp.mysite.org, I find that when accessing with Google Chrome, I only receive the "Index Of" page (see screenshot), without any content, however, when using any other web browser, the content loads properly.

[image: Index_Of]

This is not happening with connections to all ftp servers, that is, I can access to some FTP servers by using Google Chrome, but I have the issue with some other FTP servers.

I also found the bug reported in older versions of Google Chrome, but it is supposed to be fixed in newer versions:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BMn5tipPJbs

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=190117

Comment: *"the "Index Of" page, without any content"* - Means what, exactly?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Edited with the Google Chrome screenshot.

Comment: Do you have an access to FTP server logs?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, I do, the only difference I found is that when connecting with Chrome, the session is closed immediately after login. This is a log fragment (I am not authorized to share the whole log):
  
  `FTP session opened`  
  `ANON ftp: Login successful.`  
  `FTP session closed.`

Comment: And do you have an access to log of some server, where Chrome works?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Unfortunately not, I have no access to a server when Chrome works fine.